# Clearing search results and showing new results in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

Looking for advice on which way I should do this. I've gone ahead and made a search that takes form inputs and searches my db. The only issue is that if you search a second time the search appends onto the first results instead of clearing the search first. I guess my question is should I be clearing the results by using jsinterop or is there a way I can clear these results in Blazor c# via data binding? I could not find any examples online. Any advice would be appreciated!

Edit: Here is my razor component

```
@page "/search"
@using TranactionJournalV4.Models;
@using TranactionJournalV4.Data;
@using TranactionJournalV4.Controllers;

@inject SearchService searchService
@inject SearchDropDownService searchDropDownService
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
@implements IDisposable

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center pb-4">
        <MatDatePicker @bind-Value="@startDate" EnableTime="true"></MatDatePicker>
        <MatButton OnClick="@(_ =>
                      {
                          startDate = DateTime.Now;
                      })">
            Now
        </MatButton>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatSelect Label="Region" @bind-Value="@Region">
            @foreach (var region in Regions)
            {
                <MatOptionString Value="@region.RegionCode.ToString()">@region.RegionName</MatOptionString>
            }

        </MatSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatSelect Label="MCC"  @bind-Value="@Mcc">
            @foreach (var MCode in MCCs)
            {
                <MatOptionString Value="@MCode.Mcc">@MCode.Mcc - @MCode.Description</MatOptionString>
            }

        </MatSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatTextField @bind-Value="@MerchantID" Label="MerchantID"></MatTextField>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatSelect Label="Transaction Currency"  @bind-Value="@CurrencyCode">
            @foreach (var CCode in CurrencyCodes)
            {
            <MatOptionString Value="@CCode.Numeric">@CCode.Numeric - @CCode.ShortName</MatOptionString>
            }

        </MatSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatTextField @bind-Value="@TerminalID" Label="TerminalID"></MatTextField>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatTextField @bind-Value="@TxnAmount" Label="Transaction Amount"></MatTextField>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatTextField @bind-Value="@BIN" Label="BIN"></MatTextField>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatSelect Label="Message Type"  @bind-Value="@MessageType">
            @foreach (var MType in MessageTypes)
            {
            <MatOptionString Value="@MType.MessageType">@MType.MessageType - @MType.Description</MatOptionString>
            }

        </MatSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatTextField @bind-Value="@MaskedPan" Label="Masked PAN"></MatTextField>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatSelect Label="Processing Code"  @bind-Value="@ProcessingCode">
            @foreach (var procCode in ProcessingCodes)
            {
                <MatOptionString Value="@procCode.ProcessingCode"> @procCode.ProcessingCode - @procCode.Description</MatOptionString>
            }


        </MatSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatTextField @bind-Value="@ClearPan" Label="Clear PAN"></MatTextField>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatSelect Label="Response Code"  @bind-Value="@ResponseCode">
            @foreach (var ResCode in ResponseCodes)
            {
            <MatOptionString Value="@ResCode.ResponseCode">@ResCode.ResponseCode - @ResCode.Description</MatOptionString>
            }
        </MatSelect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatTextField @bind-Value="@AuthCode" Label="Authorization Code"></MatTextField>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <MatSelect Label="Entry Code"  @bind-Value="@EntryCode">
            @foreach (var entryCode in EntryModes)
            {
            <MatOptionString Value="@entryCode.EntryCode">@entryCode.EntryModeDescription</MatOptionString>
            }

        </MatSelect>
    </div>
</div>
<MatButton Outlined="true"  @onclick="@SearchTransactions">Search</MatButton>


@if (transactions == null)
{

}
else
{

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Transaction Date</th>
                <th>Merchant ID</th>
                <th>Terminal ID</th>
                <th>Trace Amount</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Authorization Code</th>
                <th>Response Code</th>
                <th>Masked PAN</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            @foreach (var transaction in NextTransactions)
            {
                <tr class="tableInfo">

                    <td>@transaction.TransactionDateTime</td>
                    <td>@transaction.MerchantID</td>
                    <td>@transaction.TerminalID</td>
                    <td>@transaction.SystemTrace</td>
                    <td>@transaction.Currency</td>
                    <td>@transaction.AuthorizationCode</td>
                    <td>@transaction.ResponseCode</td>
                    <td>@transaction.PANM</td>


                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>

    </table>
    @if (StopLoading)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>End Of List</h4>
        </div>
    }
    <div id="list-end" class="mt-5 mb-5 p-5">
        <p></p>
        @if (IsLoading)
        {
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="spinner-grow" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status">
                    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
    @*<input type="button" value="More Results" @onclick="@MoreResults" />*@
}







@code {


    private DateTime startDate;
    private string Region;
    private List<TransactionModel> transactions;
    private PaginationDTO pagination = new PaginationDTO();
    private List<TransactionModel> NextTransactions = new List<TransactionModel>();
    private string Mcc;
    private string MerchantID;
    private string TerminalID;
    private decimal TxnAmount;
    private string BIN;
    private string MaskedPan;
    private string ClearPan;
    private string AuthCode;
    private string CurrencyCode;
    private string MessageType;
    private string ProcessingCode;
    private string ResponseCode;
    private string EntryCode;



    public List<CommonMerchantCatagoryCodes> MCCs;
    public List<CommonCurrencyCodes> CurrencyCodes;
    public List<CommonPosmessageTypeRecords> MessageTypes;
    public List<CommonPosprocessingCodeRecords> ProcessingCodes;
    public List<CommonResponseCodeRecords> ResponseCodes;

    public List<EntryModes> EntryModes = new List<EntryModes>
    {
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "05", EntryModeDescription = "Chip Card"},
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "92", EntryModeDescription = "Chip Card - Fallback"},
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "02", EntryModeDescription = "Magnetic Stripe"},
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "94", EntryModeDescription = "Magnetic Stripe - No AID"},
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "01", EntryModeDescription = "Manually Keyed"},
        new EntryModes{EntryCode= "07", EntryModeDescription = "NFC"}
    };

    public List<Regions> Regions = new List<Regions>
    {
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419733", RegionName = "Antigua and Barbuda (05)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "457947", RegionName = "Aruba (16)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "457944", RegionName = "Bahamas (02)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "457944", RegionName = "Bahamas - Agency (32)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "483172", RegionName = "Barbados (15)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419640", RegionName = "Bonaire (17)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "457946", RegionName = "Cayman Islands (07)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419639", RegionName = "Curaçao (13)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "483174", RegionName = "Grenada (09)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419641", RegionName = "Saba (18)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419735", RegionName = "Saint Kitts and Nevis (11)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419736", RegionName = "Saint Lucia (12)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "483173", RegionName = "Saint Vincent (20)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "419638", RegionName = "Sint Maarten (Dutch part) (19)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "415536", RegionName = "Trinidad and Tobago (03)"},
        new Regions{RegionCode = "457945", RegionName = "Turks and Caicos Islands (14)"},

    };



    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        MCCs = searchDropDownService.GetAllMCCs().ToList();
        CurrencyCodes = searchDropDownService.GetAllCurrencies().ToList();
        MessageTypes = searchDropDownService.GetAllMessages().ToList();
        ProcessingCodes = searchDropDownService.GetAllProcessingCodes().ToList();
        ResponseCodes = searchDropDownService.GetAllResponseCodes().ToList();
    }

    async Task SearchTransactions()
    {
        //transactions = await searchService.SearchTransactionsAsync(searchTerm, pagination);
        //foreach(var txn in transactions)
        //{
        //    NextTransactions.Add(txn);
        //}


        await LoadMore();
        await InitJsListenerAsync();
    }

    //async Task MoreResults()
    //{
    //    transactions = await searchService.SearchNextResults(searchTerm, pagination);
    //}

    bool IsLoading { get; set; } = false;

    //int PageSize = 30;

    int PageNumber = 0;

    bool StopLoading = false;

    protected async Task ClearResults()
    {

    }

    protected async Task InitJsListenerAsync()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ScrollList.Init", "list-end", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task LoadMore()
    {
        if (!IsLoading)
        {
            IsLoading = true;

            StateHasChanged();

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            //for (int i = 0; i < pagination.Page; i++)

            transactions = await searchService.SearchNextResults(startDate, Region, Mcc, MerchantID, CurrencyCode, TerminalID, TxnAmount, BIN, MessageType, MaskedPan, ProcessingCode, ClearPan, ResponseCode, AuthCode, EntryCode, pagination);
            //}
            pagination.Page++;

            foreach (var txn in transactions)
            {
                NextTransactions.Add(txn);
            }
            PageNumber++;

            IsLoading = false;

            StateHasChanged();


            //at the end of pages or results stop loading anymore
            if (PageNumber > 50)
            {
                await StopListener();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task StopListener()
    {
        StopLoading = true;
        IsLoading = false;
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ScrollList.RemoveListener");
        StateHasChanged();
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ScrollList.RemoveListener");
    }

}
```

Here is my search service:

```
   public async Task<List<TransactionModel>> SearchNextResults(DateTime transactionDate, string Region, string MCC, string MerchantID, string TxnCurrency, string TerminalID, decimal TxnAmount, string BIN, string MsgType, string MaskedPan, string ProcessingCode, string ClearPan, string ResponseCode, string AuthorizationCode, string EntryMode, [FromQuery] PaginationDTO pagination)
        {
            var queryable = context.TransactionJournal.Where(s => s.LocalDateTime <= transactionDate) 
                .Where(s => Region == null || Region == s.AcquirerID)
                .Where(s => MCC == null || MCC == s.MerchantCategoryCode)
                .Where(s => MerchantID == null || MerchantID == (s.MerchantID))
                .Where(s => TxnCurrency == null || TxnCurrency == (s.Currency))
                .Where(s => TerminalID == null || TerminalID == (s.TerminalID))
                .Where(s => TxnAmount == 0 || TxnAmount == s.TransactionAmount)
                .Where(s => BIN == null || BIN == s.Bin)
                .Where(s => MsgType == null || MsgType.Trim() == s.MessageType)
                .Where(s => ProcessingCode == null || ProcessingCode == s.ProcessingCode)
                .Where(s => MaskedPan == null || MaskedPan == s.PANM)
                .Where(s => ClearPan == null || ClearPan == s.PAN)
                .Where(s => ResponseCode == null || ResponseCode == s.ResponseCode)
                .Where(s => AuthorizationCode == null || AuthorizationCode == s.AuthorizationCode)
                .Where(s => EntryMode == null || s.PosEntryMode.Contains(EntryMode))
                .AsQueryable();
            var orderedQuery = queryable.OrderByDescending(x => x.LocalDateTime);
            await HttpContextExtensions.GetPage<TransactionModel>(orderedQuery, pagination.Page, pagination.QuantityPerPage);
            return await orderedQuery.Paginate(pagination).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Could you please share us your code

Comment: @FabianKamp let me know if you want to see anything else

Comment: What if you do NextTransactions.Clear() in LoadMore() method ?

Comment: @auburg My nexttransactions is using infinite scroll and pulls up the next 25 transactions for the query unless I am mistaken that would just start clearing the results of my current search no?

Comment: ok - so do it in SearchTransactions method which is where you do a new search ?

Comment: That worked! I guess I was overthinking on what to do thanks for the simple answer!

Comment: What hapens if you make your LoadMore method sync and start the load serviceSearcher thing with `Task.Run(() => serviceSearcher....).Wait();` that would be my suggestion what you can try.

Answer (score 1):

As auburg mentioned I added nexttransaction.clear() to the searchtransactionmethod